# CSS fadein animation not working on a Safari browser

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm having some problems using CSS animations, I developed my code using Chrome, but now I'm testing it on different browsers I'm having trouble running it on a Safari browser.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r965um2t/2/#&togetherjs=Sle1FMxyMn)

My CSS code

```
.fade-in {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;
    -moz-animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;
    -o-animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;
    animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
    -moz-animation-duration: .5s;
    -o-animation-duration: .5s;
    animation-duration: .5s
}
.one {
    -webkit-animation-delay: .2s;
    -moz-animation-delay: .2s;
    -o-animation-delay: .2s;
    animation-delay: .2s
}
.two {
    -webkit-animation-delay: .5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: .5s;
    -o-animation-delay: .5s;
    animation-delay: .5s
}
.three {
    -webkit-animation-delay: .8s;
    -moz-animation-delay: .8s;
    -o-animation-delay: .8s;
    animation-delay: .8s
}
.four {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.3s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1.3s;
    -o-animation-delay: 1.3s;
    animation-delay: 1.3s
}
.five {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.7s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1.7s;
    -o-animation-delay: 1.7s;
    animation-delay: 1.7s
}
.six {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.2s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 2.2s;
    -o-animation-delay: 2.2s;
    animation-delay: 2.2s
}
```

What this code dose is order a fadein animation when the page loads.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your code doesn't implement the `fadeIn` animation. It wouldn't work in Chrome either. Did you forget to add it to the fiddle? If not, look into the `@keyframes` syntax to specify what you want fadeIn to do.

Comment: That helped me more than you think, I'm just blind :) All fixed now thank you